# Mixing Basic Auth and Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, basic-authentication

I have a website with some areas that require a login via forms-based authentication, using my own provider that connects to the database.

The website is in preview so I want to protect the entire site via basic auth to prevent unauthorized access before it goes live.

The problem is when basic and forms auth is on the pages that will be public go to the forms login instead.

How can I keep the forms based authentication for member login and portal access, but protect the entire site from public access before go-live by using basic auth?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to satisfy your use case in the following manner.

Within the site .Net Authorization Rules create a Deny rule for anonymous users.

At the site Authentication enable Basic and Forms authentication.  Disable all other authentication types.  This should require all users to be authenticated with basic authentication to use the base site and then require forms login to the parts of the site that requires your custom authentication.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried but that but have the same problem. The problem is  all ASP.NET pages (controllers) require login, even ones that have the [AllowAnonymous] attribute added, described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx.

Comment: I have been using MVC3 and got this to work "On My Machine", which I know doesn't help.  With the above configuration I have a custom LogonAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute filter which excludes some controllers from requiring filtering.  if (!(filterContext.Controller is AccountController))
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }  . I am not sure how this would interact with the AllowAnonymous Attribute (which I will use when I move to MVC4).

Comment: I tried added a check for the controller as you've shown in the code above but still the same problem :( I think I need some http module or something as IIS complains with "You cannot use both a challenge-based authentication method and a login redirection-based authentication method at the same time". This is a temporary situation so I don't really want to dig into the intricacies of mixed authentication processing or writing http modules if I can help it! It's strange to me that IIS/Asp.Net can't handle a global block (basic auth) and forms based login when my forms login is based off a db.

Comment: is the problem being solved? I have the same problem now.